# Functional component to class component Error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a small project and am in the process of translating a functional component to a class based component so that my component can manage its state. In translating the component over, I've run into an error:

> TypeError:Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

This component worked as a functional component so I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error now. Can anyone answer why in translating from a functional component to a class based one that I'm receiving this error? Is this something to do with scope at all? Do I just have some syntax wrong? I've been banging my head against this for a while and just can't understand why it cannot read the property of 'id' which is in now in the return of the render portion of my component.

Component code:

```
  import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./OpenTasksComponent.css"



class openTasks extends Component{
  constructor(){
      super();

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

     handleClick(){
        let x = document.body.nodeName;
        console.log(x);
    }
    
    render(){

        return (
    
            <div className="tasks" value = {this.task.id}>
                <h1 onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.task.clientName}</h1>
                <div className="accordion-item accordion-item-open">
                    <h2>{this.task.matter}</h2>
                    <p>{this.task.matterStatus}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        )

    }
    
    
}

export default openTasks
```

App code:

```
import './App.css';
import Task from './components/open-tasks-component/open-tasks-component';
import tasksData from './components/open-tasks-component/tasks-data';
import Header from './Header';

function App() {
  const Tasks = tasksData.map(task=> <Task key={task.id} task ={task}/>)
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Header />
    
        {Tasks}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You want to use `this.props.task`

Comment: Use the useState hook in your functional component? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: @Will I don't know how to use hooks yet. Still learning the basics of react and i'm working on class based components but I appreciate that this is another method to address giving functional components a way to manage state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App you passed a prop down, but you tried to read it in the child class component using `this.task.id` it should be `this.props.task.id`

Comment: Thank you Rachid. This worked. Can you explain why this is necessary when moving from the functional component to the class based one? Wasn't i passing down a prop before?

Comment: no worries, I'm not sure what you're component looked like before, but you probably had "functionComponent({prop1,prop2})" destruct syntax, you could do the same in your class component inside the render something like "const {prop1, prop 2} = this.props"

Comment: essentially I had everything in the return statement just no handleClick() method and no constructor. yet, it worked with this.task.id

Answer (score 0):

Functional components can also manage states.
You can use useState.

```
const [state, setState] = useState(null);
```

Comment: I understand but I have not advanced to learn hooks yet. I'm currently working with class based and functional components without hooks.  Once I have learned hooks, i'm sure i'll start implementing them.